# how to populate comvobox in vba through windows api?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to populate combobox in VBA via any api or something else ..
I want to avoid hard coded entries

```
Set FontList = Application.CommandBars("Formatting").FindControl(ID:=1728)

'   If Font control is missing, create a temp CommandBar
If FontList Is Nothing Then
    Set Tempbar = Application.CommandBars.Add
    Set FontList = Tempbar.Controls.Add(ID:=1728)
End If

'   Put the fonts into column A
'Range("A:A").ClearContents
For i = 0 To FontList.ListCount - 1
   cbmFontList.value = FontList.List(i + 1)
Next i

'   Delete temp CommandBar if it exists
On Error Resume Next
Tempbar.Delete
```

I am trying this code but it is not working.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're populating a combo box. It looks like you're populating an Excel worksheet _from_ a combo box. Is that what you need to do?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention Combobox.. i edited my post now can you please help me.